# Select telemetry data based on relational data in PostgreSQL/TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, join, query, aggregate, timescaledb

I'm trying to solve a particularly difficult problem. I am storing some telemetry data from some sensors in an SQL table (PostgreSQL) and I want to know how I can I write a query that will group the telemetry data using relational information from two other tables.

I have one table which stores the telemetry data from the sensors. This table contains three fields, one for the timestamp, one for the sensor ID, one for the value of the sensor at that time. The value column is an incrementing count (it only increases and never resets)

**Sensor_Telemetry** table

| **timestamp** | **sensor_id** | **value** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 5 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:01 | 5 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:02 | 5 | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 5 | 675 |

I have another table which stores the state of the sensor, whether it was stationary or in motion and the start/end dates of that particular state for that sensor:

**Status** table

| **start_date** | **end_date** | **status** | **sensor_id** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00 | in_motion | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:20:00 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00 | stationary | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:40:00 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | in_motion | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The sensor is located at a particular location. The Sensor table stores this metadata:

**Sensor** table

| **sensor_id** | **location_id** |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 16 |

In the final table, I have the shifts that occur in each location. The shift table is a list of occurrences of all shifts, ie in this case Shift A is defined to occur every day between 00:00:00 and 00:30:00, Shift B is defined to occur every day between 00:30:00 and 01:00:00. So then the Shift table would have records like so:

**Shift** table

| **shift** | **location_id** | **occurrence_id** | **start_date** | **end_date** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A Shift | 16 | 123 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 |
| B Shift | 16 | 124 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 |
| A Shift | 16 | 123 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 2022-01-02 00:30:00 |
| B Shift | 16 | 124 | 2022-01-02 00:30:00 | 2022-01-02 01:00:00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to write a query so that I can retrieve telemetry data that is grouped both by the shifts at the location of the sensor as well as the status of the sensor, selecting by giving a date range:

| **sensor_id** | **start_date** | **end_date** | **status** | **shift** | **value_start** | **value_end** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00 | in_motion | A Shift | 3 | 250 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 | stationary | A Shift | 25 | 325 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00 | stationary | B Shift | 325 | 490 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | in_motion | B Shift | 490 | 675 |

As you can see, the telemetry data would be grouped both by the information contained in the Shift table as well as the Status table. Particularly, if you notice the sensor was in a `stationary` status between 2022-01-01 00:20:00 and 2022-01-01 00:40:00, however if you notice the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> rows in the above table, this is cut into two rows based on the fact that the shift had changed at 2022-01-01 00:30:00.

Is it possible to write a query that can do this? I would really appreciate it you have any ideas, thanks!

Link to db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sAXudT8qB35WWBk9xREj7p/6

Comment: What can we assume that we know in advance? Can we assume that a) shift A will always be the first 30 mins of the hour and shift b the second one? Can we always assume that the status Stationary/In-Motion will always be on a 20 minute rota - on the hour, on the 20 and on the 40 minute marks?

Comment: I've messed  aroun with this - as you can see from below. It appears to me that your scenario is **impossible** to solve without having a `location_id` in the telemetry table!

Answer (score 4):

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/R_A6I09J):

```
select distinct
    sensor . sensor_id,
    shift  . shift,
    shift  . occurence_id,
    status . status,
    status . status_id,
    MIN(st.datetime) OVER w as start_date,
    MAX(st.datetime) OVER w as end_date,
    FIRST_VALUE(st.reading) OVER w as reading_start,
    LAST_VALUE(st.reading) OVER w as reading_end,
    MIN(st.reading) OVER w as reading_min,
    MAX(st.reading) OVER w as reading_max
from 
    status
  join sensor
           using (sensor_id)
  join shift
           on sensor.location_id = shift.location_id
          and (status.start_date, status.end_date) OVERLAPS 
              (shift.start_date, shift.end_date)
  join sensor_telemetry as st
           on st.sensor_id = sensor.sensor_id
          and tstzrange( 
                  GREATEST(status.start_date, shift.start_date), 
                  LEAST(status.end_date,   shift.end_date) 
              ) @> st.datetime
where 
    status.sensor_id = 5 
window w as
( partition by 
    sensor . sensor_id, 
    shift  . shift, 
    shift  . occurence_id, 
    status . status, 
    status . status_id
  order by 
    st.datetime
  rows between unbounded preceding 
           and unbounded following
)
order by 
    start_date ;
```

And a bit simpler answer if we only require the MIN/MAX of the readings, not the first/last (or as the OP says we know that they always coincide): https://dbfiddle.uk/hbIcLpNn

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I've arrived at by making use of the OVERLAPS() function, let me know if you can improve this!

**Schema (PostgreSQL v11)**

```
create table sensor_telemetry(
  datetime TIMESTAMPTZ,
  sensor_id int,
  reading bigint
  );
  
insert into sensor_telemetry (datetime, sensor_id, reading) values
('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z', 5, 1),
('2020-01-01T00:00:01Z', 5, 2),
('2020-01-01T00:00:02Z', 5, 3),
('2020-01-01T00:00:03Z', 5, 4),
('2020-01-01T00:00:04Z', 5, 5),
('2020-01-01T00:00:05Z', 5, 6),
('2020-01-01T00:00:06Z', 5, 7),
('2020-01-01T00:00:07Z', 5, 8),
('2020-01-01T00:00:08Z', 5, 9),
('2020-01-01T00:00:09Z', 5, 10),
('2020-01-01T00:00:10Z', 5, 11),
('2020-01-01T00:00:11Z', 5, 12),
('2020-01-01T00:00:12Z', 5, 13),
('2020-01-01T00:00:13Z', 5, 14),
('2020-01-01T00:00:14Z', 5, 15),
('2020-01-01T00:00:15Z', 5, 16),
('2020-01-01T00:00:16Z', 5, 17),
('2020-01-01T00:00:17Z', 5, 18),
('2020-01-01T00:00:18Z', 5, 19),
('2020-01-01T00:00:19Z', 5, 20),
('2020-01-01T00:00:20Z', 5, 21),
('2020-01-01T00:00:21Z', 5, 22),
('2020-01-01T00:00:22Z', 5, 23),
('2020-01-01T00:00:23Z', 5, 24),
('2020-01-01T00:00:24Z', 5, 25),
('2020-01-01T00:00:25Z', 5, 26),
('2020-01-01T00:00:26Z', 5, 27),
('2020-01-01T00:00:27Z', 5, 28),
('2020-01-01T00:00:28Z', 5, 29),
('2020-01-01T00:00:29Z', 5, 30),
('2020-01-01T00:00:30Z', 5, 31),
('2020-01-01T00:00:31Z', 5, 32),
('2020-01-01T00:00:32Z', 5, 33),
('2020-01-01T00:00:33Z', 5, 34),
('2020-01-01T00:00:34Z', 5, 35),
('2020-01-01T00:00:35Z', 5, 36),
('2020-01-01T00:00:36Z', 5, 37),
('2020-01-01T00:00:37Z', 5, 38),
('2020-01-01T00:00:38Z', 5, 39),
('2020-01-01T00:00:39Z', 5, 40),
('2020-01-01T00:00:40Z', 5, 41),
('2020-01-01T00:00:41Z', 5, 42),
('2020-01-01T00:00:42Z', 5, 43),
('2020-01-01T00:00:43Z', 5, 44),
('2020-01-01T00:00:44Z', 5, 45),
('2020-01-01T00:00:45Z', 5, 46),
('2020-01-01T00:00:46Z', 5, 47),
('2020-01-01T00:00:47Z', 5, 48),
('2020-01-01T00:00:48Z', 5, 49),
('2020-01-01T00:00:49Z', 5, 50),
('2020-01-01T00:00:50Z', 5, 51),
('2020-01-01T00:00:51Z', 5, 52),
('2020-01-01T00:00:52Z', 5, 53),
('2020-01-01T00:00:53Z', 5, 54),
('2020-01-01T00:00:54Z', 5, 55),
('2020-01-01T00:00:55Z', 5, 56),
('2020-01-01T00:00:56Z', 5, 57),
('2020-01-01T00:00:57Z', 5, 58),
('2020-01-01T00:00:58Z', 5, 59),
('2020-01-01T00:00:59Z', 5, 60),
('2020-01-01T00:01:00Z', 5, 61),
('2020-01-01T00:01:01Z', 5, 62),
('2020-01-01T00:01:02Z', 5, 63),
('2020-01-01T00:01:03Z', 5, 64),
('2020-01-01T00:01:04Z', 5, 65),
('2020-01-01T00:01:05Z', 5, 66),
('2020-01-01T00:01:06Z', 5, 67),
('2020-01-01T00:01:07Z', 5, 68),
('2020-01-01T00:01:08Z', 5, 69),
('2020-01-01T00:01:09Z', 5, 70),
('2020-01-01T00:01:10Z', 5, 71),
('2020-01-01T00:01:11Z', 5, 72),
('2020-01-01T00:01:12Z', 5, 73),
('2020-01-01T00:01:13Z', 5, 74),
('2020-01-01T00:01:14Z', 5, 75),
('2020-01-01T00:01:15Z', 5, 76),
('2020-01-01T00:01:16Z', 5, 77),
('2020-01-01T00:01:17Z', 5, 78),
('2020-01-01T00:01:18Z', 5, 79),
('2020-01-01T00:01:19Z', 5, 80),
('2020-01-01T00:01:20Z', 5, 81),
('2020-01-01T00:01:21Z', 5, 82),
('2020-01-01T00:01:22Z', 5, 83),
('2020-01-01T00:01:23Z', 5, 84),
('2020-01-01T00:01:24Z', 5, 85),
('2020-01-01T00:01:25Z', 5, 86),
('2020-01-01T00:01:26Z', 5, 87),
('2020-01-01T00:01:27Z', 5, 88),
('2020-01-01T00:01:28Z', 5, 89),
('2020-01-01T00:01:29Z', 5, 90),
('2020-01-01T00:01:30Z', 5, 91),
('2020-01-01T00:01:31Z', 5, 92),
('2020-01-01T00:01:32Z', 5, 93),
('2020-01-01T00:01:33Z', 5, 94),
('2020-01-01T00:01:34Z', 5, 95),
('2020-01-01T00:01:35Z', 5, 96),
('2020-01-01T00:01:36Z', 5, 97),
('2020-01-01T00:01:37Z', 5, 98),
('2020-01-01T00:01:38Z', 5, 99),
('2020-01-01T00:01:39Z', 5, 100),
('2020-01-01T00:01:40Z', 5, 101),
('2020-01-01T00:01:41Z', 5, 102),
('2020-01-01T00:01:42Z', 5, 103),
('2020-01-01T00:01:43Z', 5, 104),
('2020-01-01T00:01:44Z', 5, 105),
('2020-01-01T00:01:45Z', 5, 106),
('2020-01-01T00:01:46Z', 5, 107),
('2020-01-01T00:01:47Z', 5, 108),
('2020-01-01T00:01:48Z', 5, 109),
('2020-01-01T00:01:49Z', 5, 110),
('2020-01-01T00:01:50Z', 5, 111),
('2020-01-01T00:01:51Z', 5, 112),
('2020-01-01T00:01:52Z', 5, 113),
('2020-01-01T00:01:53Z', 5, 114),
('2020-01-01T00:01:54Z', 5, 115),
('2020-01-01T00:01:55Z', 5, 116),
('2020-01-01T00:01:56Z', 5, 117),
('2020-01-01T00:01:57Z', 5, 118),
('2020-01-01T00:01:58Z', 5, 119),
('2020-01-01T00:01:59Z', 5, 120),
('2020-01-01T00:02:00Z', 5, 121)
;
  
  
  
create table status(
  sensor_id int,
  status_id int,
  start_date timestamptz,
  end_date timestamptz,
  status varchar(15)
  );
  
insert into status (sensor_id, status_id, start_date, end_date, status) values
(5, 8, '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z', '2020-01-01T00:01:30Z', 'stationary'),
(5, 9, '2020-01-01T00:01:30Z', '2020-01-01T00:01:45Z', 'in_motion'),
(5, 10, '2020-01-01T00:01:45Z', '2020-01-01T00:02:00Z', 'stationary');
  
create table sensor(
  sensor_id int,
  location_id int
  );
  
insert into sensor (sensor_id, location_id) values
(5, 16);
  
create table shift(
  shift varchar(15),
  location_id int,
  occurence_id int,
  start_date timestamptz,
  end_date timestamptz
  );
  
insert into shift (shift, location_id, occurence_id, start_date, end_date) values
('Shift A', 16, 123, '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z', '2020-01-01T00:01:00Z'),
('Shift B', 16, 124, '2020-01-01T00:01:00Z', '2020-01-01T00:02:00Z');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with statuses as (
  select 
    stat.sensor_id,
    stat.status,
    stat.status_id,
    stat.start_date,
    stat.end_date,
    sens.location_id
  from status stat
  inner join sensor sens on (sens.sensor_id = stat.sensor_id)
  where stat.sensor_id=5
),
shift_status as (
  select 
    sa.sensor_id,
    s.shift,
    s.occurence_id,
    s.start_date as shift_start,
    s.end_date as shift_end,
    sa.status,
    sa.status_id,
    sa.start_date as status_start,
    sa.end_date as status_end
  from shift s
  inner join statuses sa on 
    (sa.location_id = s.location_id
     and (sa.start_date, sa.end_date)  OVERLAPS (s.start_date, s.end_date))
),
phases as (
  select 
    sensor_id,
    shift,
    occurence_id,
    status,
    status_id,
    GREATEST(shift_start, status_start) as start_date,
    LEAST(shift_end, status_end) as end_date
  from shift_status 
  order by start_date
)
select 
    st.sensor_id,
    shift,
    occurence_id,
    status,
    status_id,
    MIN(datetime) as start_date,
    MAX(datetime) as end_date,
    MIN(reading) as reading_start,
    MAX(reading) as reading_end
from sensor_telemetry st
inner join phases p on 
    (st.sensor_id = p.sensor_id
     and (p.start_date, p.end_date) overlaps (st.datetime, st.datetime))
group by st.sensor_id, shift, occurence_id, status, status_id
order by start_date;
```

| sensor_id | shift | occurence_id | status | status_id | start_date | end_date | reading_start | reading_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Shift A | 123 | stationary | 8 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2020-01-01T00:00:59.000Z | 1 | 60 |
| 5 | Shift B | 124 | stationary | 8 | 2020-01-01T00:01:00.000Z | 2020-01-01T00:01:29.000Z | 61 | 90 |
| 5 | Shift B | 124 | in_motion | 9 | 2020-01-01T00:01:30.000Z | 2020-01-01T00:01:44.000Z | 91 | 105 |
| 5 | Shift B | 124 | stationary | 10 | 2020-01-01T00:01:45.000Z | 2020-01-01T00:01:59.000Z | 106 | 120 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sAXudT8qB35WWBk9xREj7p/6)

Comment: I don't think the `MAX` and `MIN(reading)` give you the reading start and end, only the max and min in the duration of each group. Getting the first (start) and last (end) reading is going to be a bit more tricky.

Comment: For me it's acceptable in this case - I know for sure that the reading can only increment in time, as it's not possible for it to decrement to a lower value. But you're right, the logic is not exactly correct in the general case

Answer (score 3):

I looked at this, quite thought-provoking +1!

To answer something like this, good data is essential (edge cases &c.), so I did the following, in particular simulating data using PostgreSQL's really powerful `GENERATE_SERIES()` feature (see [here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/03/14/fun-with-sql-generate-sql/), [here](https://www.timescale.com/blog/how-to-create-lots-of-sample-time-series-data-with-postgresql-generate_series/) and [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-srf.html)).

All of the code below (and more) is available on the fiddles within the various answers' sections. I've put in `INDEX`es and `FOREIGN KEY`s because I'd like to test (both on db<>fiddle and at home) the performance of the different approaches - in particular to see how the PostgreSQL `GIST index` (see [here](https://medium.com/postgres-professional/indexes-in-postgresql-5-gist-86e19781b5db) and [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/gist-intro.html)) works out.

### 1st answer - and general range based approach ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btMQ4ZfS)):

I've added a `location` table to the OP's ones - it makes the scenario more realistic (IMHO) and will come into play for testing on multiple locations.

```
CREATE TABLE location
(
  location_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  l_desc      TEXT    NOT NULL
);
```

Only 1 record for the moment:

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES (16, 'Farm');
```

Following the OP's setup for `sensor` - names of fields have been changed slightly.

```
CREATE TABLE sensor
(
  sensor_id    SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  location_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT loc_FK FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location (location_id)
);

CREATE INDEX sensor_l_ix ON sensor(location_id);
```

populate:

```
INSERT INTO sensor VALUES (5, 16);
```

We only need one, because the solution(s) (will) take care of the grouping by sensor and location.

```
CREATE TABLE telemetry
(
  t_ts      TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  sensor_id INTEGER     NOT NULL,
  t_val     INTEGER     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tel_pk PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id, t_ts),  -- can only have one (set of) measurements 
                                                    -- at the same time - only t_val
  CONSTRAINT tel_sens_fk FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) REFERENCES sensor (sensor_id)
);
```

then:

```
INSERT INTO telemetry
SELECT
  ('2022-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ + (INTERVAL '1 SECOND' * (i - 1))), 5, i
FROM
(
  SELECT
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, 21700) AS i
) AS t;
```

I used PostgreSQL's `GENERATE_SERIES()` function to simulate ~20k data points - time incrementing by 1 second, and the value by 1 - seems to be what the OP requires.

```
CREATE TABLE status
(
  start_tz  TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  end_tz    TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  ms        TEXT        NOT NULL,
  sensor_id SMALLINT    NOT NULL
);
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO status
SELECT
  GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 06:20:00', INTERVAL '20 MINUTES'),
  GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-01 00:20:00', '2022-01-01 06:40:00', INTERVAL '20 MINUTES'),
  CASE
    WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN 'in_motion)'
    ELSE                     'stationary'
  END,
  5;   -- <<== only one sensor - could have put in others using GENERATE_SERIES()
```

and now the shifts:

```
CREATE TABLE shift
(
  shift_id     TEXT        NOT NULL,
  location_id  SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
  occurence_id SMALLINT    NOT NULL, 
  start_tz     TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  end_tz       TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);
```

populate - shifts every thirty minutes - `A` & `B`.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    16 AS loc,
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, 15, 1) AS occur,
    GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 07:00:00', INTERVAL '30 MINUTE')
      AS start_tz,
    GENERATE_SERIES('2022-01-01 00:30:00', '2022-01-01 07:30:00', INTERVAL '30 MINUTE')
      AS end_tz
)
INSERT INTO shift
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM start_tz) = 0 THEN 'Shift A'
      ELSE 'Shift B'
    END,
    loc,
    occur,
    start_tz,
    end_tz
  FROM cte;
```

Now, we use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) function ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)) and the `%` modulo operator! I've included fields that were not strictly necessary in order to demonstrate my train of thought!

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sensor_id, s.location_id 
                              ORDER BY st.start_tz, sh.start_tz) AS rn,

  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sensor_id, s.location_id 
                              ORDER BY st.start_tz, sh.start_tz) % 4 AS mod,  
  CASE 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sensor_id, s.location_id 
                              ORDER BY st.start_tz, sh.start_tz) % 4
      WHEN 1 THEN  TSTZRANGE(st.start_tz, st.end_tz)
      WHEN 2 THEN  TSTZRANGE(st.start_tz, sh.end_tz)  -- alternates - see TIMEs
      WHEN 3 THEN  TSTZRANGE(sh.start_tz, st.end_tz)  -- alternates - see TIMEs
      WHEN 0 THEN  TSTZRANGE(st.start_tz, st.end_tz)
  END AS range_date,      
  sh.occurence_id,
  st.start_tz::TIME AS st_start, st.end_tz::TIME AS st_end,  -- ::TIME for legibility
  sh.start_tz::TIME AS sh_start, sh.end_tz::TIME AS sh_end
  
FROM sensor s
  JOIN status st USING (sensor_id)
  JOIN shift  sh USING (location_id)
WHERE (st.start_tz, st.end_tz) OVERLAPS (sh.start_tz, sh.end_tz)
ORDER BY rn, mod, range_date;
```

Result (snipped for brevity):

```
rn  mod               range_date                       occurence_id st_start    st_end  sh_start    sh_end
 1    1 ["2022-01-01 00:00:00+00","2022-01-01 00:20:00+00") 1   00:00:00    00:20:00    00:00:00    00:30:00
 2    2 ["2022-01-01 00:20:00+00","2022-01-01 00:30:00+00") 1   00:20:00    00:40:00    00:00:00    00:30:00
 3    3 ["2022-01-01 00:30:00+00","2022-01-01 00:40:00+00") 2   00:20:00    00:40:00    00:30:00    01:00:00
 4    0 ["2022-01-01 00:40:00+00","2022-01-01 01:00:00+00") 2   00:40:00    01:00:00    00:30:00    01:00:00
 5    1 ["2022-01-01 01:00:00+00","2022-01-01 01:20:00+00") 3   01:00:00    01:20:00    01:00:00    01:30:00
```

Now, we can see that for every instance of the `mod` field being `= 1` we have the start of a new hour - so, tidying up and joining to the `telemetry` table, the final query is:

```
SELECT
  t.sensor_id AS s_id, sub.location_id AS loc_id, 
  sub.t_val AS "S_val", t.t_val AS "E_val", 
  sub.range_date, sub.occurence_id AS oc_id, sub.ms   -- can have other fields...
FROM
  telemetry t
JOIN
(  
  SELECT 
    t.sensor_id, t.t_val,
    sh.occurence_id, sh.location_id, st.ms,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sensor_id, s.location_id 
      ORDER BY st.start_tz, sh.start_tz) % 4 AS rn,
  
    CASE 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sensor_id, s.location_id 
                             ORDER BY st.start_tz, sh.start_tz) % 4
        WHEN 1 THEN  TSTZRANGE(st.start_tz, st.end_tz)
        WHEN 2 THEN  TSTZRANGE(st.start_tz, sh.end_tz)
        WHEN 3 THEN  TSTZRANGE(sh.start_tz, st.end_tz)
        WHEN 0 THEN  TSTZRANGE(st.start_tz, st.end_tz)
    END AS range_date     
                
FROM sensor s
  JOIN status    st USING (sensor_id)
  JOIN shift     sh USING (location_id)
  JOIN telemetry t  USING (sensor_id)
WHERE (st.start_tz, st.end_tz) OVERLAPS (sh.start_tz, sh.end_tz)
  AND t.t_ts = CASE
                  WHEN sh.start_tz > st.start_tz THEN sh.start_tz
                  ELSE st.start_tz
                END                 -- <<=== Note JOIN on CASE!
) AS sub
ON t.t_ts = UPPER(range_date) - INTERVAL '1 SECOND'
ORDER BY range_date;
```

Result (snipped for brevity):

```
s_id loc_id S_val E_val                 range_date                       oc_id     ms
   5     16     1  1200 ["2022-01-01 00:00:00+00","2022-01-01 00:20:00+00") 1   stationary
   5     16  1201  1800 ["2022-01-01 00:20:00+00","2022-01-01 00:30:00+00") 1   in_motion)
   5     16  1801  2400 ["2022-01-01 00:30:00+00","2022-01-01 00:40:00+00") 2   in_motion)
   5     16  2401  3600 ["2022-01-01 00:40:00+00","2022-01-01 01:00:00+00") 2   stationary
   5     16  3601  4800 ["2022-01-01 01:00:00+00","2022-01-01 01:20:00+00") 3   stationary
```

### 2nd answer - an exclusively range based approach ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gT60xYQy))

The setup is similar - except that I used the `TSTZRANGE` types in my table declarations<sup>(*)</sup> and used GIST indexes to index those columns - check the fiddle.

<sup>(*) Tables `status` and `shift`</sup>

The major differences between this answer and the 1st one is that the range syntax considerably enhances the legibilty of the final query and 2nd (to my mind anyway) makes the problem easier to reason about. The final query is as follows (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gT60xYQy) for setup and logic):

```
SELECT
  t.sensor_id AS s_id, sub.location_id AS loc_id, 
  sub.t_val AS "S_val", t.t_val AS "E_val", 
  sub.range_date, sub.ms, sub.occurence_id AS oc_id  -- can have other fields...
FROM
  telemetry t
JOIN
(  
  SELECT 
    t.sensor_id, t.t_val,
    sh.occurence_id, st.ms, sh.location_id,
  
  CASE 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.sensor_id, s.location_id ORDER BY st.datran, sh.datran) % 4
      WHEN 1 THEN st.datran
      WHEN 2 THEN TSTZRANGE(LOWER(st.datran), UPPER(sh.datran))
      WHEN 3 THEN TSTZRANGE(LOWER(sh.datran), UPPER(st.datran))
      WHEN 0 THEN  st.datran  
  END AS range_date      

FROM sensor s
  JOIN status    st USING (sensor_id)
  JOIN shift     sh USING (location_id)
  JOIN telemetry t  USING (sensor_id)
WHERE (st.datran) && (sh.datran)     -- Note the && range type OVERLAPS operator!
AND t.t_ts = GREATEST(LOWER(st.datran), LOWER(sh.datran))  -- alternative to CASE
) AS sub
ON t.t_ts = UPPER(range_date) - INTERVAL '1 SECOND'
ORDER BY range_date;
```

Result - same as for the first query. If it wasn't, then it would be incorrect!

### 3rd answer - using EXTRACT  ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tzbCGq6B))

This solution is a bit weaker in the sense that it assumes knowledge of the distribution of the data points - i.e. on the hour, 20, 30, 40, next hour. But the OP told us that - and we can easily change this to suit any configuration.

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT
  t1.t_ts, t1.t_val, t1.sensor_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.sensor_id ORDER BY t1.t_ts) AS rn1
FROM 
  telemetry t1
WHERE 
     EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t1.t_ts) =  0 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t1.t_ts) = 0
  OR EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t1.t_ts) = 20 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t1.t_ts) = 0
  OR EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t1.t_ts) = 30 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t1.t_ts) = 0
  OR EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t1.t_ts) = 40 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t1.t_ts) = 0 
UNION ALL -- because there can't be any duplicates, so no need to sort and filter!
SELECT
  t2.t_ts, t2.t_val, t2.sensor_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.sensor_id ORDER BY t2.t_ts) AS rn2
FROM 
  telemetry t2
WHERE 
     EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t2.t_ts) = 19 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t2.t_ts) = 59
  OR EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t2.t_ts) = 29 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t2.t_ts) = 59
  OR EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t2.t_ts) = 39 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t2.t_ts) = 59
  OR EXTRACT('MINUTE' FROM t2.t_ts) = 59 AND EXTRACT('SECOND' FROM t2.t_ts) = 59
  ORDER BY t_ts
),
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    cx.rn1, cx.sensor_id AS sid, cx.t_ts AS t1, cy.t_ts AS t2, cx.t_val AS sv, cy.t_val AS ev
  FROM
    cte1 AS cx
  JOIN cte1 AS cy
    ON cx.rn1 = cy.rn1 AND cx.t_ts != cy.t_ts AND cx.t_val < cy.t_val
)

SELECT
  st.sensor_id AS sid, sh.location_id AS lid, cte2.rn1, -- rn1 not strictly necessary - left in to demonstrate!

  CASE rn1 % 2 
    WHEN 1 THEN sh.start_tz
    ELSE        st.start_tz
  END AS t1,

  CASE rn1 % 2 
    WHEN 1 THEN st.start_tz
    ELSE        sh.end_tz
  END AS t2,  
  
  sh.occurence_id AS oc_id, st.ms, 
  sh.shift_id AS sh_id 
  
FROM
  shift sh
JOIN status st
  ON (sh.start_tz, sh.end_tz) OVERLAPS (st.start_tz, sh.end_tz)
JOIN cte2
  ON st.sensor_id = cte2.sid
WHERE sh.start_tz <= st.start_tz AND sh.end_tz <= st.end_tz 
AND (cte2.t1, cte2.t2) OVERLAPS (sh.start_tz, sh.end_tz) 
ORDER BY sh.start_tz, sh.end_tz;
```

Result - same as for the first query. If it wasn't, then it would be incorrect!

### Preliminary Performance Analysis: (TBD)

The usual caveats apply! It's impossible to get reliable benchmark figures from

- a system where I don't have a clue what's running at the same time - this is all the more true for a server that's exposed to the internet!
- a system which is configured with a very small number of records relatively speaking - I also did this:

  SET enable_seqscan = off;
  SET enable_nestloop = off;

  It remains to be seen (coming to a screen near you soon!) what happens when I perform these tests with a large number of records on a beefy home server with nothing else happening and without the "tricks" above.